# Is passing along contact information encouraged?

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/cps-breaching-court-order) question, the answerer briefly posted, and then deleted, an email address for further contact.  The presence of the word "detective" in the address, of course, may or may not be indicative of a profession.

It got me thinking more broadly.  Is there a distinction between passing along contact information and soliciting business on SE?  Is either governed by policy?  The lack of a PM feature is discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user).

Answer (score 4):

A comment was flagged for moderator attention automatically, as it contained an email address.

[Can we have a moderator only “flag for community team/developer attention” link on posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259239/260340):

> Someone posting their email address in a post seeking a reply probably isn't sensitive; presumably they intended to do that, so just edit it out & tell them to not be selfish.

I deleted the comment, as well as the reply, as it became a non sequitur.

The substantive answer to your question is that we generally don't recommend posting your personal information here, and soliciting business is governed by [How not to be a spammer](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

There's at least [one other discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117/260340) about potentially sensitive information.

However, if the discussion just needs to be, well, a discussion, you can use chat. There's no real accommodation for discussions that need to be *private*, though, as your linked question states.